# MUC in iOS using robbiehanson XMPPframework

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, multiuserchat

What is the step by step procedure to implement MUC in iOS using robbiehanson XMPPframework?

I tried allocating the room, then activating the stream and joining the room.

But I got a response as follows:

```
 <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="room@XXXXX.com" to="user@XXXXX.com/34633017701337944885586135" type="error" id="4DD4A6E2-E24F-4D38-AD87-15070B6AD90E"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"/></query><error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Also received an iq : `xmppStream:didReceiveIQ: - 4DD4A6E2-E24F-4D38-AD87-15070B6AD90E`

Comment: i am also struggling with the same error

Comment: Hello Peter, I am Stuck in MUC, Have you found any working solution or Approach with MUC ? Thanks.

Comment: @Mangesh, As I already answered below, While creating or joining the room, the format should be yourRoomName@conference.YourDomainName.com. The conference is the keyword here. If you add the keyword conference, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. It may help someone. While creating or joining the room, the format should be `yourRoomName@conference.YourDomainName.com`. The `conference` is the keyword here.

Comment: Thanks mate, I had the same problem in this completely solved it :)

Comment: Happy to see that it helped someone... :)

Comment: Hey, i'm having issue of delegate mehtods not being called, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765641/ios-xmppframework-creating-xmpproom   can you share your code?