# XMPPFramework - Create an XMPPRoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I have been trying to create a XMPPRoom using the below mentioned code, i have looked at various examples online however when i use this code, the delegate xmppRoomDidCreate or xmppRoomDidJoin delegates doesn't get called. I'm not sure what am i doing wrong here?

PS: the delegates of xmppStream do get called, it gets connected and authorized however, the issue is XMPPRoom delegates...

```
- (void)createChatRoom
{
    NSString *jabberID = @"abcxyz@testservice.com";
    self.xmppStream.hostName = @"testservice.com";


    self.xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc]init];
    [self.xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [self.xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cannot connect to server %@",[error localizedDescription]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        return;
    }

    // Configure xmppRoom
    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"TestRoom@conference.testservice.com"];

    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];

    XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage
                                                           jid:roomJID
                                                 dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom activate:self.xmppStream];
    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}
```

Comment: One of the best which helped me, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24179388/563735

Comment: @rohitmandiwal Malik, Have you found any solution ?

Comment: yes @Mangesh, please find at the bottom on this trail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you add `<XMPPRoomDelegate>` protocol in the .h file of the view controller in which you want to monitor XMPPRoom's delegates?

It should be something like this: `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <..., XMPPRoomDelegate>`.

Of course `#import "XMPPRoom.h"` should be also in .h file of the mentioned view controller.

ADDITION:

You have to setup `XMPPStream` object, connect to your 'chat' server (in most cases Jabber server) with `XMPPJID`, then listen for server response, then authentificate with the password and then to start with `XMPPRoom` creation if everything mentioned from above goes well.

Example:

```
- (void)setupStream
{
    NSAssert(xmppStream == nil, @"Method setupStream invoked multiple times");
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];

    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}
```

Then to connect to server:

```
[self setupStream];

NSString *myJID = @"...";

[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];

NSError *error2;
if ([xmppStream connect:&error2])
{
    NSLog(@"Connected to XMPP.");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error connecting to XMPP: %@", [error2 localizedDescription]);
}
```

Listen for server response (do not forget to add `<XMPPStreamDelegate>` in .h file):

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{    
    NSError *error;    
    if ([[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Authentificated to XMPP.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error authentificating to XMPP: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Listen for server response for authentification status:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"available"];
    [sender sendElement:presence]; 
}
```

and then try to create XMPPRoom by calling function after authentification success:

```
- (void)createChatRoom
{    
    // Configure xmppRoom
    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"TestRoom@conference.testservice.com"];

    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];

    XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage
                                                           jid:roomJID
                                                 dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom activate:self.xmppStream];
    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:user history:nil];
}
```

Comment: yes, i have added <XMPPRoomDelegate> in .h file, and i can confirm this as after the above code executes, after like a min one of the XMPPRoom protocol gets called - (void)xmppRoomDidLeave:(XMPPRoom *)sender

Comment: Do you know if i have to connect and authorize XMPPStream object before attempting to create XMPPRoom? do you have any example?

Comment: Also, maybe in your code you need just this line 
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:user history:nil]; where the user is an username of your chat avatar, but I would also implemented these XMPPStream delegates for cases when connection to the server is not successful.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I followed all the steps you mentioned in your answer, i can see on eJabbered that the room has been created However, XMPPRoom delegates "didCreate" or "DidJoin" were not fired however, one of XMPPStream delegate - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
 got fired with presence type "error" :(

Comment: Yes, of course, after authorization you will have to sent your presence to the server (that can be done inside - (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender). It would be something like: XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"available"];[[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];

Comment: Also, example from my answer is modified version of the code from this link https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework. When you download XMPPFramework library it comes with Xcode project example.

Comment: Hey @Sihad, can you help me with bookmark xmpprooms? do you have any example or documents that can help me? i already read 0048 but that is not very clear on how to bookmark a conference group and then retrieve them back.

Comment: here is the actual question link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792739/ios-xmpp-frame-work-xep-0048-bookmark-storage

Comment: Fetching configuration is missing in your answer. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24179388/563735

Comment: Hello All, Thanks you all and starckoverflow, I am able to create group  and send Invitations to other with Both Storage (Core data & Memory Storage). Issue is when I create Second group it removes first group data from Core data storage and Also How can we auto join other user ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution worked for me. You have to implement `XMPPRoomDelegate`

```
- (void)createChatRoom
{

    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];

    /**
     * Remember to add 'conference' in your JID like this:
     * e.g. uniqueRoomJID@conference.yourserverdomain
     */

    NSString *groupName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.192.168.0.101",groupNameTextField.text];
    NSLog(@"attempting to create room %@",groupName);
    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:groupName];
    XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomStorage
                                                           jid:roomJID
                                                 dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom activate:del.xmppStream];
    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self
            delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:[self appDelegate].xmppStream.myJID.user
                            history:nil
                           password:nil];

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"groupChatArray"]];
    [array addObject:groupName];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:array forKey:@"groupChatArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm{
    NSLog(@"didFetchConfigurationForm");
    NSXMLElement *newConfig = [configForm copy];
    NSLog(@"BEFORE Config for the room %@",newConfig);
    NSArray *fields = [newConfig elementsForName:@"field"];

    for (NSXMLElement *field in fields)
    {
        NSString *var = [field attributeStringValueForName:@"var"];
        // Make Room Persistent
        if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_persistentroom"]) {
            [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
            [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"AFTER Config for the room %@",newConfig);
    [sender configureRoomUsingOptions:newConfig];
}
```

Comment: Cool. I was missing **conference** in room XMPPJID