# XMPPFramework - XEP-0048: Bookmark Storage

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

In my app, I have implemented creating XMPPRoom and inviting users. Now, I am searching for a way to store these groups (my created or the groups i have been invited to) so that i can easily retrieve it back in my app when I want. I came across bookmark XEP-0048 however, I can't find any example of using this online. Has anyone used this before? Can you please share some examples?

> http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/attic/xep-0048-1.0.html

Ahmad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [XEP-0048: Bookmarks](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0048.html), to upload bookmarks to server, you have to send a `iq` request like this:

```
<iq from='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony' type='set' id='pip1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <publish node='storage:bookmarks'>
      <item id='current'>
        <storage xmlns='storage:bookmarks'>
          <conference name='The Play&apos;s the Thing' 
                      autojoin='true'
                      jid='theplay@conference.shakespeare.lit'>
            <nick>JC</nick>
          </conference>
        </storage>
      </item>
    </publish>
    <publish-options>
      <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
          <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publish-options</value>
        </field>
        <field var='pubsub#persist_items'>
          <value>true</value>
        </field>
        <field var='pubsub#access_model'>
          <value>whitelist</value>
        </field>
      </x>
    </publish-options>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

In Objective-C using NSXMLElement class, above XML can be written as this:

```
    NSXMLElement *pubsub = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"pubsub" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"];
    NSXMLElement *publish = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"publish"];
    [publish addAttributeWithName:@"node" stringValue:@"storage:bookmarks"];
    NSXMLElement *item = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"item"];
    [item addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"current"];
    NSXMLElement *storage = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"storage" xmlns:@"storage:bookmarks"];
    NSXMLElement *conference = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"conference"];
    [conference addAttributeWithName:@"name" stringValue:@"The Play&apos;s the Thing"];
    [conference addAttributeWithName:@"autojoin" stringValue:@"true"];
    [conference addAttributeWithName:@"jid" stringValue:@"theplay@conference.shakespeare.lit"];
    NSXMLElement *nick = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"nick" stringValue:@"JC"];
    [conference addChild:nick];
    [storage addChild:conference];
    [item addChild:storage];
    [publish addChild:item];

    NSXMLElement *publish_options = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"publish-options"];
    NSXMLElement *x = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"x" xmlns:@"jabber:x:data"];
    [x addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"submit"];
    NSXMLElement *field1 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"field"];
    [field1 addAttributeWithName:@"var" stringValue:@"FORM_TYPE"];
    [field1 addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"hidden"];
    NSXMLElement *value1 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publish-options"];
    [field1 addChild:value1];
    [x addChild:field1];
    NSXMLElement *field2 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"field"];
    [field2 addAttributeWithName:@"var" stringValue:@"pubsub#persist_items"];
    NSXMLElement *value2 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"whitelist"];
    [field2 addChild:value2];
    [x addChild:field2];
    [publish_options addChild:x];

    [pubsub addChild:publish];
    [pubsub addChild:publish_options];

    XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"set" child:pubsub];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"juliet@capulet.lit/balcony"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"pip1"];
```

Of course it could be written with only one NSXMLElement, something like

```
NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"iq" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"all xml code from first paragraph with %@ to add your dynamic data...", data1, data2, ...];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"juliet@capulet.lit/balcony"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"pip1"];
```

After iq has been created it is time to send it to the server like

```
[xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

and this is the way bookmarks are sent to server. You listen for server response in in XMPPStream delegate `- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq` and server response should be something like this:

```
<iq to='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony' type='result' id='pip1'/>
```

or in objective-c code:

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    if([iq isResultIQ])
    {
        if([[iq attributeStringValueForName:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"pip1"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Bookmarks with id %@ succesfully uploaded", [iq attributeStringValueForName:@"id"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, based on example from above create objective-c code for xml with which clinet is requesting bookmarks from server ([XEP-0048: Bookmarks 3.3 Retrieving Data](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0048.html#storage-pubsub-retrieve)):

```
<iq from='juliet@capulet.lit/randomID' type='get' id='retrieve1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <items node='storage:bookmarks'/>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

objective-c code:

```
NSXMLElement *pubsub = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"pubsub" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"];
NSXMLElement *items = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"items"];
[items addAttributeWithName:@"node" stringValue:@"storage:bookmarks"];
[pubsub addChild:items];

XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"get" child:pubsub];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"juliet@capulet.lit/balcony"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"retrive1"];
```

send it to the server like before:

```
[xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

and listen for server response like before:

```
<iq type='result'
    to='juliet@capulet.lit/randomID'
    id='retrieve1'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <items node='storage:bookmarks'>
      <item id='current'>
        <storage xmlns='storage:bookmarks'>
          <conference name='The Play&apos;s the Thing' 
                      autojoin='true'
                      jid='theplay@conference.shakespeare.lit'>
            <nick>JC</nick>
          </conference>
        </storage>
      </item>
    </items>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```

or objective-c code:

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{

    if([iq isResultIQ])
    {
        if([[iq attributeStringValueForName:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"retrive1"])
        {
            NSXMLElement *pubsub = [iq elementForName:@"pubsub"];
            NSArray *items = [pubsub elementsForName:@"items"];

            NSLog(@"Bookmarks for id %@ are: %@", [iq attributeStringValueForName:@"id"], items);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sihad, Is it true that i have to send all the bookmarked conferences when adding a bookmark, because if i do it individually, it will overwrite? if yes, how do i send multiple elements in [xmppStream sendElement:iq], or do i have to use a for loop?

Comment: From this http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0223.html#composition you will see that each data is stored as separated item. You will notice for every item there is an id that says this bookmark is unique (if not added, it will be added by server). Please, try to experiment. Add more then one item nodes and see what will happen? Also, take a look at these xmpp extensions XEP-0060, XEP-0223 for more info about storing bookmarks. There are xmpp framework functions for XEP-0060, XEP-0223

Comment: For sending mutiple elements to server, just create mutiple iq like iq1, iq2, iq3, ... and send them like [xmppStream sendElement:iq1], [xmppStream sendElement:iq2], [xmppStream sendElement:iq3], ...

Comment: @DevCali did you manage to update bookmark list without overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a group or accepts a chatroom invitation, store the group to local database with the necessary information. Delete it from db while exiting the group.

Answer (score 1):

Get User groups from jabber server.

```
  XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc]init];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
    NSString *from = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ResouseName",[[AppDelegate instance] xmppStream].myJID.bare];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:from];
    NSXMLElement *query =[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:private"];
    NSXMLElement *storage =   [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"storage" xmlns:@"storage:bookmarks"];
    [query addChild:storage];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

Answer (score 0):

You very easy to doing this way.
Please try this.
you can add to bookmark in server using this method.

```
-(void)bookMark :(NSString *)roomName{ 

  XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc]init];
 [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];
NSString *from = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ResouseName",[[AppDelegate instance] xmppStream].myJID.bare];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue: from];    
 NSXMLElement *query =[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:private"];
 NSXMLElement *storage =   [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"storage" xmlns:@"storage:bookmarks"];
NSXMLElement *conference_s = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"conference"];
[conference_s addAttributeWithName:@"autojoin" stringValue:@"true"];
[conference_s addAttributeWithName:@"jid" stringValue:roomName];    
[storage addChild:conference_s];
[query addChild:storage];
[iq addChild:query];    
NSLog(@"print eml log %@:",iq);
[xmppStream sendElement:iq];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally you can get your group list.

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq {

NSXMLElement *pubsub = [iq elementForName:@"query"];

NSXMLElement *storage = [pubsub elementForName:@"storage"];

 NSArray *conferenceName = [storage elementsForName:@"conference"];
for (NSXMLElement *conference in conferenceName) {
    NSString *jid = [[conference attributeForName:@"jid"]stringValue];
     NSLog(@"print conference jid=====%@",jid);

}
 NSLog(@"Bookmarks for id are: %@", conferenceName);
```