# Retrieve users and groups and creating users and group in Ejabber XMPP iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I'm using Ejabber XMPP server with a HOST and port. currently i'm developing the app using simulator. I'm able to get list of user(online/offline) but my requirement is to get list of  **users and groups at once** to display in same screen and **groups separately** again to display in another screen. i'm using coredata stroage. How to store the contacts added/information in server along with local.

For adding a user i'm using the below method. it is not saving in server only locally it is saving.

```
XMPPJID *newBuddy = [XMPPJID jidWithString:self.buddyField.text];
[self.xmppRoster addBuddy:newBuddy withNickname:@"ciao"];
```

For creating Group i tried the below link, it says created but i'm not able to see that list of groups i'm not sure that the group is added or not unless i can retrieve the group info.

[XMPPFramework - Create an XMPPRoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765641/xmppframework-create-an-xmpproom)

Please help me.

***Note:** Android app is already developed, in that i have registered with my credentials to test i'm using same credentials in iOS also. If i add a contact Android app i'm able to see in simulator. If i add a contact in iOS app it is showing in my simulator only in Android app it is not updating.

Comment: What exactly you mean under "Group"? Groupchat or groups in user contact list? How you create group under android? Please explain or show some working code

Comment: @vitalyster  like whatsapp, i want to retrieve list of groups and contacts.. so i can start chat with individual or with group. here i'm trying to retrieve the groups alone. i followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268629/xmppframework-implement-group-chat-muc . but delegate methods are not calling